# showing error while installing logstash-filter-rest message: certificate verify failed

Tags: logstash

I am installing https://github.com/lucashenning/logstash-filter-rest
and getting below error.

I am trying to make rest api call in logstash.

> bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-rest
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.util.SecurityHelper to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.util.SecurityHelper
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
>   ERROR: Updated Aborted, message: Plugin logstash-filter-rest is not installed so it cannot be updated, aborting

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to logstash-filter-rest is not installed in your machine.
Because logstash-filter-rest is not a built in plugin its an external plugin.

Please try the below command

/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-rest